# Java - How to set String as static int

Tags: java

I have a method that accepts only a String.

```
public void setVerticalAlignment(String align) {
            ...
    gd.verticalAlignment = align;   // accepts only int.
            ...
}
```

But `gd.verticalAlignment` only accepts an int. 
Usually this is set by something like `gd.verticalAlignment = SWT.TOP` where SWT.TOP is a static int.

is it possible to call this method with something like `setVerticalAlignment("SWT.TOP")`?

Comment: Why don't you just convert the string? Integer.parseInt(align);

Comment: Why do you use a String for the alignment at all??

Comment: Change `setVerticalAlignment(String align)` to `setVerticalAlignment(int align)` and call call `obj.setVerticalAlignment(SWT.TOP)`.

Comment: You can use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).

Comment: im parsing from a text field. so the input is string. so I set the type as a String...

Comment: I think this is the classical XY Problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Java 7 you can always use `switch` on Strings:

```
switch (align) {
    case "SWT.TOP":
        gd.verticalAlignment = SWT.TOP;
    /* etc */
}
```

Being honest I would avoid using strings like `"STW.TOP"`. If I really had to store alignment state in the other way than just `int` I would use enums which might be used in `switch` in older versions of Java.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want a map:

```
// Ideally use ImmutableMap from Guava
private static final Map<String, Integer> ALIGNMENTS = mapAlignments();

private static final Map<String, Integer> mapAlignments() {
    Map<String, Integer> ret = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    ret.put ("SWT.TOP", SWT.TOP);
    // etc
    return ret;
}
```

Then you can just fetch from the map (and unbox) later.

Or, better, change your method declaration to avoid this in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer.parseInt(String)
```

can throw a [NumberFormatException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if the string is not specified as integer value. 
Also in prev versions of java, you cant apply switch-case on Strings. So better you can use the following :

```
if(("SWT.TOP").equals(align))
{
     gd.verticalAlignment = SWT.TOP;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a text field? There are only a few legal choices for alignments, so you should really use something like a [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) instead. You could store  custom objects in the JComboBox so that they display the named constant but also store the integer constant:

```
public class SwingAlignOption {
  public final String name;
  public final int value;
  public SwingAlignOption(String name, int value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }
  public String toString() { return name; }
}
```

Then you can add instances to the combo-box like `comboBox.addItem(new SwingAlignOption("TOP", SWT.TOP))`.

Note that JComboBox changed between Java 6 and 7. In the Java 7 libraries JComboBox is generic, which makes it easier to store custom objects like this inside and retrieve their values later. In Java 6 you'll have to use a cast when you access the selected value.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. In that case, I'd suggest using the `Map` or `switch` option suggested above instead.