# How to set String as static int?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - How to set String as static int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069026/java-how-to-set-string-as-static-int)

I have a method that accepts only a String.

```
public void setVerticalAlignment(String align) {
...
gd.verticalAlignment = align; 
// accepts only int.   
... 
}
```

But `gd.verticalAlignment` only accepts an int. Usually this is set by something like `gd.verticalAlignment = SWT.TOP` where `SWT.TOP` is a static int.

is it possible to call this method with something like `setVerticalAlignment("SWT.TOP")`?

Comment: Yes, that's possible—but not simply implemented. Frankly, if you're trying to pass in the name of class and constant member as a string there's probably something wrong with your design. Why is the value being passed in as a string?

Comment: How was it possible not to see [the existing question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069026/java-how-to-set-string-as-static-int) ? Is that just a repost from the same user (now anonymous) ? A colleague ?

Comment: @dystroy - There is no way that two people came up with the exact same question with the same wording and example code independently.

Answer (score 1):

If `align` is a number in string format. then you can do :

```
gd.verticalAlignment = Integer.parseInt(align);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Swing constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html) or something like that if you're rolling out your own framework

Answer (score 0):

you can, with casting to string. But you should not do that. You should change your code inside your method and call gd.verticalAlignment = Integer.valueOf(align);

Comment: It's better to directly call `Integer.parseInt` because Integer.valueOf(String) is the same as `new Integer(Integer.parseInt(s))`. Getting new Integer object is superfluous when you just need a raw int.